# Как отобразить xml документ в с#

Tags: c#, xml

Добрый день. Столкнулась с проблемой создания "своего" языка для вёрстки. Для этого хотелось бы использовать такой элемент в Windows.Forms как webbrowser. Он отображает html страницы по заданному коду. Я хочу через xml и xsl добиться отображения страницы со своей разметкой. Подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: То есть вы хотите предложить свой собственный язык вместо HTML? Ну, если его можно будет «перегнать» в HTML, то наверное за неделю-другую управиться можно, написав плагин для браузера. Или может быть он будет отображаться на WinForms или там WPF. Если нет — пару лет работы на написание собственного движка.

Comment: я имею ввиду тот же html, только со своими тегами. Попросту говоря нужно чтобы webbrowser(в с#) прочитал xml и выдал страницу согласно xsl документу. Я надеюсь это задание реальнее чем "нарисовать прямые линии в форме котёнка")

Comment: Ну это придётся веббраузеру объяснить, что делать с вашим XML. Поскольку задача браузера — отображать именно HTML, а не что-то другое, то так просто этого не добиться. Либо есть какая-нибудь подпольная возможность заставить его понимать ваш формат, либо (скорее всего) вам придётся самостоятельно написать код, который перегоняет из вашего формата в HTML, и скармливать браузеру.

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону `vue.js`, он позволяет создавать свои компоненты, теги HTML, правда на основе имеющихся.

Comment: Все зависит от того, наколько порезан движок в компоненте WebBrowser. Просто я не пробовал его так использовать. Копайте в сторону XSLT преобразований. Дефолтный IE умеет такое корректно отображать налету, если правильно прописать в исходном XML линки на файлы преобразований.

Comment: и перенесите пожалуйста ваш комментарий в [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/796087/edit), чтобы было понятно, что именно вы хотите сделать из текста самого вопроса.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> я имею ввиду тот же html, только со своими тегами. Попросту говоря нужно чтобы webbrowser(в с#) прочитал xml и выдал страницу согласно xsl документу.

Компонент `WebBrowser` является оберткой над Internet Explorer (далее IE). IE поддерживает обработку таблиц преобразований по-умолчанию, в отличие от других движков (Crome, например, этого не умеет без плагинов). Чтобы этим воспользоваться, необходимо добавить в преобразуемый XML-файл ссылку на XSL-файл, который необходимо у нему применить, перед отображением.

Пусть у нас есть следующий файл трансформаций test.xsl ([пример отсюда](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=cdcatalog)):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<html> 
<body>
  <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
  <table border="1">
    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
      <th style="text-align:left">Title</th>
      <th style="text-align:left">Artist</th>
    </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="artist"/></td>
    </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

И файл с исходными данными test.xml ([полный текст](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=cdcatalog))

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog>
  <cd>
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>Columbia</company>
    <price>10.90</price>
    <year>1985</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Hide your heart</title>
    <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>CBS Records</company>
    <price>9.90</price>
    <year>1988</year>
  </cd>
</catalog>
```

Тогда для автоматического преобразования исходного файла, согласно правилам файла трансформаций, необходимо добавить ссылку на файл трансформаций. Сделать это можно так:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="test.xsl"?>
<catalog>
    ......
</catalog>
```

Теперь, если оба файла лежат в одной папке, указываете компоненту `WebBrowser` в свойстве `Url` путь к файлу test.xml и смотрите на результат преобразования.

Естественно, вы можете хранить файлы преобразований где угодно, просто укажите правильную ссылку в заголовке и проверьте доступность XSL-файлов перед использованием.

---

XSLT-преобразования можно применить и [вручную](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/using-xslt-to-transform-an-xml-tree), если по какой-то причине они у вас не обрабатываются.

---

Корректность работы может зависеть от наличия и версии установленного Internet Explorer (не проверял). В моем случае результаты не отличались как для .NET 2.0, так и для всех последующих версий. Компонент `WebBrowser` не отличается высоким качеством и полнотой реализации функций браузера. Так что есть не нулевая вероятность, что далеко не все, что вам захочется он сможет сделать и показать правильно. Впрочем, если в результате требуется статический HTML без JavaScript и сложных CSS-стилей, проблем быть не должно.

Comment: Ого, круто, не знал.

Comment: @VladD угу, круто, только почему-то остальные браузеры так не умеют без дополнительных шаманств с плагинами и т.п.=(

Comment: Ну, эта фича как бы не требуется от браузера, браузер по сути должен отображать только HTML, а остальное опционально. Но то, что IE умеет XML + XSL, это хорошая дополнительная фишка.